# Parse Perl range string such as "1,4..7,10,11"

Tags: perl, parsing, eval

Given a *string* such as `1,4..7,10,11`, is there a neat way to parse it into the list `(1,4,5,6,7,10,11)`? The string is given as a command-line argument. My plan is ensure that the string fits `/^[0-9.,]+$/` and then `eval` it, but is there a neater way without `eval`?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @Jens I don't understand, I just wrote that in the question. I don't have a problem implementing it, just wondering if there's a neater solution without using `eval`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2816816/1030675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at CPAN module [Text::NumericList](http://search.cpan.org/~grudziar/Text-NumericList-0.01/NumericList.pm).

Converting strings into arrays:

```
use Text::NumericList;
my $list = Text::NumericList->new;

$list->set_string('1-3,5-7');
my @array = $list->get_array;     # Returns (1,2,3,5,6,7)
```

or

```
$list->set_string('1..3,5...7');
@array = $list->get_array;        # Returns (1,2,3,5,6,7)
```

As @dgw has mentioned in comment other possible modules are:

[Number::Range](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range)
[Set::Intspan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan)

Comment: Other possible modules are: [Number::Range](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range) or [Set::Intspan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) just to name two other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the simplest and ugly solution is to use `split` and `eval` like this:

```
$str = "1,4..7,10,11";

my @out;
for (split ",", $str) {
    if (/\d+\.\.\d+/) {
        eval('push @out, $_ for '.$_);
    }
    else {
        push @out, $_;
    }
}
print "(", join(',', sort {$a <=> $b} @out), ")";
```

You can avoid `eval` by extracting the two members of your range with `/([0-9]+)[.][.]([0-9]+)/` also writable `/(\d+)\.{2}(\d+)/`:

```
$str = "1,4..7,10,11";

my @out;
for (split ",", $str) {
    if (/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/) {
        push @out, $_ for $1 .. $2;
    }
    else {
        push @out, $_;
    }
}
print "(", join(',', sort {$a <=> $b} @out), ")";
```

From this we can simplify the code:

```
$str = "1,4..7,10,11";

my @out;
for (split ",", $str) {
    push @out, $_ for (/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/)? $1 .. $2: $_; 
}
print "(", join(',', sort {$a <=> $b} @out), ")";
```

Last but not least, If you are using `bash` and your input string is passed to your program as an argument. You can use the brace expansion like this:

```
$ echo 1 2 {3..6} 10 11 | sort
1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel when there are many Modules on CPAN that are better tested and documented. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I strongly agree with your argument. But sometime it is not possible to install CPAN modules. In my company we have no access to CPAN and the people that use Perl scripts don't know how to manually install all the missing modules and all their dependencies. Also, this kind of problem is quite simple and following the KISS rule we do not always need a complex module (that require to be installed) in order to solve very simple and specific tasks.

Comment: If you eval anyway, why not just eval the entire string? `@out = eval "(1,4..7,10,11)";`